# How can I split rows in excel based on a specific criteria?

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out a way to split a given set of customers into equally sized territories based on their known potential. Taking the example below I would need to split the **50** customers into **5** territories, **10** customers each with their potential summing up to approximately the average potential of the whole set **25.5** in the example worksheet.

Is that even possible in Excel? Would like to keep it in Excel to be able to share as a template, but I am opened to any other possibilities.

Thank you in advance

```
Customer    Potential
Customer 1  1
Customer 2  2
Customer 3  3
Customer 4  4
Customer 5  5
Customer 6  6
Customer 7  7
Customer 8  8
Customer 9  9
Customer 10 10
Customer 11 11
Customer 12 12
Customer 13 13
Customer 14 14
Customer 15 15
Customer 16 16
Customer 17 17
Customer 18 18
Customer 19 19
Customer 20 20
Customer 21 21
Customer 22 22
Customer 23 23
Customer 24 24
Customer 25 25
Customer 26 26
Customer 27 27
Customer 28 28
Customer 29 29
Customer 30 30
Customer 31 31
Customer 32 32
Customer 33 33
Customer 34 34
Customer 35 35
Customer 36 36
Customer 37 37
Customer 38 38
Customer 39 39
Customer 40 40
Customer 41 41
Customer 42 42
Customer 43 43
Customer 44 44
Customer 45 45
Customer 46 46
Customer 47 47
Customer 48 48
Customer 49 49
Customer 50 50
```

Comment: Why not just start at the extremes, group those together, and keep going? I.e. your first group is Customers 1, 50, 2, 49, 3, 48, 4, 47, 5, 46 ? Then next group is 6, 45, 7, 44, 8, 43, 9, 42, 10, 41, etc?

Comment: If you want a more random selection, you could grab a random customer 5 times (to give you 10 numbers) and then pair it with the number that gives you a total of 51 for the pair.  Cycle through the numbers 5 times and you would have your 5 lists.

Comment: The logic would like to apply would be Bruce's one, but was wondering if I could do this in Excel in some sort of automated way, because once the data sets become bigger it becomes too tedious to do it manually. For example for a set of 5000 customers split into groups of 500.